# I wanna write an iterative suite in excel using vba code ,

Tags: excel, iteration, vba

I wanna write an iterative suite in excel using vba code , but i don't know how to use columns adress in a variable , i mean how to loop from :for example (from A1 to XYZ1 ) 
i mean how can i increment by 1 ;from A1 to XYZ1 for exemple 
My essential goal is to execute this module :

```
Sub LoopSelection()

    ActiveSheet.Range("A00001","A11").Cut Destination:=Range("B1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A00011","A21").Cut Destination:=Range("C1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A00021","A31").Cut Destination:=Range("D1")
    .............................................................
    ActiveSheet.Range("A34971","A34981").Cut Destination:=Range("EDO1")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A34981","A34991").Cut Destination:=Range("EDP1")

End Sub
```

(but it displays :procedure too large)
i've searched a lot but there is no exact clear answer ,and if there is a way to split it 
then can i save it and re-use it automatically again
Thanks in advance

Comment: Be aware that the ranges overlap by one cell; for example **A11**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44696910/62576

Comment: I couldn’t imagine why a workbook would contain data stored with this structure but you need to declare a variable “i” and increment this by adding 10 to each i when the loop completes. Then range(“A”&i&”A”&i+10) until last row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using your code with test data, this is what you are asking to accomplish.

[image]

What you need is to set up a loop to accomplish this.

The code Loops down column 1 to the last used row, Stepping 10
Starting at A1, you resize to select the 11 cells you want to cut, and paste to your variable 'c' (for the column number), 'c' is then incremented by 1, and the loop will drop down to 11 and start again, etc. etc.

Code...

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim c As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = 2

For i = 1 To lRow Step 10
    Cells(i, 1).Resize(11).Cut Destination:=Cells(1, c)
    c = c + 1
Next i
```

This will accomplish what you are asking for.